# How to scroll scrollView to position of inner View

Tags: android

I have a view which is not at the root level of the "ScrollView". If i set `scrollTo(0, view.getTop())` it won't work, it'll scroll just a bit, I am guessing because the view is not in the root container of the `ScrollView`.

My view tree is somewhere along the lines of:

```
ScrollView 
   - LinearLayout
        - CardView
           - RelativeLayout
              - LinearLayout
                   - MyView
```

Any ideas how I can move the scrollview precisely to `MyView.getTop()` position ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mainScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

It Should work.

Answer (score 0):

I used below code for showing a popupWindow at specific location , check if its working in your case

```
 val location = locateView(view)  // here view will be the view to which you want to scroll
 scrollview.scrollTo(0, location.top)
```

and locateview function is

```
fun locateView(v: View?): Rect? {
    var loc_int = IntArray(2)
    if (v == null) return null;
    try {
        v.getLocationOnScreen(loc_int)
    } catch (e : NullPointerException) {
        return null
    }
    val location = Rect()
    location.left = loc_int[0]
    location.top = loc_int[1]
    location.right = location.left + v.width
    location.bottom = location.top + v.height
    return location
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but above the scrollview I have another view, and also the notification bar ... Seems the value takes those into consideration as well. Hmm. I guess I could also get the screen location of the scrollview, get top of that, and then substract that from the top of MyView

Comment: Ya , It takes those into consideration as well .

Comment: Yeah, no, I can't make it work. I've added the top portion as well, but it goes beyond the scrollview, it scrolls more than it should, not sure why.